# Roman to Arabic Listing Caption Numbering

Tags: formatting, listings, lstlisting, roman

I'm working on my thesis that uses many code listing in it. In each listing, I want to put caption with the chapter number followed by the position of that listing on that chapter. The problem is my thesis uses Roman numbering for the chapter yet I want to use Arabic numbering for my listing caption. So, for example my first chapter (Chapter I), I want to caption the first listing as Listing 1.1. Here is small sample text that describe my problem.

```
\documentclass[a4,12pt]{report}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    Here is chapter 1
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=First Listing,frame=single]
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        printf("Hello World");
        return 0;
    }
    \end{lstlisting}
    \chapter{Analysis}
    Here is chapter 2
    \begin{lstlisting}[caption=Second Listing,frame=single]
        #include <stdio.h>

        int main()
        {
        printf("Hello World");
        return 0;
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way that I can maintain using Roman numbering for the chapter but using Arabic one for the listing caption? Thank you for the help.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{lstlisting}}` should work, but consider that using Roman chapter numbers for the real chapters and arabic numbers for chapter numbers in compound listing numbers may be confusing. `1.1` could be misunderstood as Listing 1 from section 1

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I got this error when adding that command `\thelstlisting undefined. \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}`

Comment: I remember that `listings` does define the `lstlisting` counter after `\begin{document}`, so using `\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{...}` in the preamble will fail. Try `\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{lstlisting}}}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I still got the same error

Comment: It works for me with the code you posted.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Is there any package that I missed or something?

Comment: As I wrote: I used the code you posted and `\AtBeginDocument{...}` as stated already... above. No extra package

Comment: Ah yes it works, apparently I put that command before `\usepackage{listings}` so that's why it doesn't work at first. Thank you so much for your help @ChristianHupfer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments